# Polymer paper-input binding always text

Tags: polymer

I have the following polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-input/iron-input.html">

<dom-module id="number-input">
    <template>
        <paper-input type="number" label="amount" value="{{amount}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "number-input",
            properties: {
                amount: {
                    type: Number,
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The "amount" property is always a string. Even though I define the property as a "Number". Am I missing something or is this normal behaviour ?

Sander.

Comment: Input values are always Strings regardless of what you set your property type to.

Comment: The value is always a string. If you set the input type, however, on an ordinary html element you will get a different user interface, e.g. a numeric keypad on a touch device rather than an full keyboard, and input is automatically limited to numbers.

Comment: Add an observer for the amount property and perform the string to number conversion yourself in the observer and assign the result back to the property.  paper-input is return the value that comes back from the the underly input element - that value is always a string.

Comment: @jptknta Why doesn't polymer do the type conversion for you if you bound to a Number property?!

Comment: I can't say one way or another why it doesn't automatically convert to a Number. Perhaps Polymer is simply matching the existing html input element behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use an ordinary input field directly and specify is="iron-input" and type="number". The type attribute is what ultimately gets you the number field you are looking for. Other number input attributes such "min" should work as well.

You add a label, validator, and error message, around that as described by the polymer paper-input-container [documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a default `value` to 0 and use `pattern` for input validation:

```
<dom-module id="number-input">
<template>
    <paper-input type="number" label="amount" value="{{amount}}" pattern="\d+\.?\d*"></paper-input>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "number-input",
        properties: {
            amount: {
                type: Number,
                value:0
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```